# Linux IPC: cannot remove msqid_ds

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue

This seems a strange behaviour but I need to keep my msqid_ds otherwise I get a SIGABRT. The code is very simple:

```
void printMessageQueueInfo(int queue_id){

  // IPC_STAT: get descriptor structure
  // IPC_SET: set descriptor (only permissions can be changed)
  // IPC_RMID: remove message queue
  if(msgctl(queue_id, IPC_STAT, &info) == -1){
      perror("Cannot retrieve information about the message queue");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("------------------------------\n");
  printf("MESSAGE QUEUE %d\n", queue_id);
  printf("Permissions:\n\
  Owner   uid: %u\n\
  Owner   gid: %u\n\
  Creator uid: %u\n\
  Creator gid: %u\n\
  Mode       : %o\n", info.msg_perm.uid, info.msg_perm.gid, info.msg_perm.cuid, info.msg_perm.cgid, info.msg_perm.mode);
  printf("Time last message send     : %d\n", info.msg_stime);
  printf("Time last message received : %d\n", info.msg_rtime);
  printf("Time last change           : %d\n", info.msg_ctime);
  printf("Number of messages         : %d\n", info.msg_qnum);
  printf("Maximum bytes              : %d\n", info.msg_qbytes);
  printf("PID last sender            : %d\n", info.msg_lspid);
  printf("PID last receiver          : %d\n", info.msg_lrpid);
  printf("------------------------------\n");
}
```

the struct info needs to be global.

If I define it inside this function I get `stack smashing detected`, I believe that happen when the msqid_ds get out of scope and the kernel reply with an abort when I tried to delete the structure. This is my guess, but why this happen? Am I doing something wrong? I also notice that if I got the msqid_ds I'll get the same error if I attempt to remove the queue (`msqctl(queue_id, IPC_RMID, 0)`) right after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. msqid_ds is for 32-bit system, if you are operating on a 64-bit machine the corresponding structure is msqid64_ds.

This is implementation specific, I should have included  instead of